# conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid.in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on windows form application ..i have a code like this:

```
 Dim strarr() As String = dr(0).ToString().Split(New Char() {"-"c})
 Dim i As Integer = 0   
 i = strarr(0) + 1
 creditinvoiceno = i
```

**my strarr(0) value is  INV100001** i want to add +1 to this number ..
that s why i given code like this, but i am getting error
**conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid.**

Comment: It's a string. You can't put strings into integers directly. You need to parse the string.

Comment: That's because `INV10001` is not a number. You need to remove the `INV`, convert, do the increment and then add the `INV` back on

Comment: You've to type cast your variable

Comment: can u show me a sample code

Comment: i try to add code like this  i= Integer.Parse(strarr(0)) + 1  but still getting error'

Comment: `Integer.Parse` will only work if the string is an integer. You need to remove the `INV` part of the string and then parse. `Int32.Parse(strarr(0).Substring(3))`

Comment: after that how i can add INV to corresponding value?

Comment: Convert the integer back to a string and use the `&` concatenation operator: `("INV" & i.ToString())`

Comment: this time getting error:Conversion from string "INV100002" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: sir actually i am trying to assign this value ("INV" & i.ToString()) to my i variable ..that is right or wrong

Comment: Well, you need to assign the value to a **string** variable, not an **int32** (aka. integer) variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strarr() As String = dr(0).ToString().Split(New Char() {"-"c})
Dim i As Integer = Int32.Parse(strarr(0).Replace("INV", string.Empty))
i = i + 1
strarr(0) = "INV" & i.ToString()
creditinvoiceno = i
```